# Creating a Huawei Map programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, maps, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-map-kit

I'm creating programmatically a **Huawei** map, but despite MapFragment() is a child of Fragment class, the transaction add doesn't recognize it as a Fragment. Here's my code:

```
val transaction: FragmentTransaction = activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
val mapFragment = MapFragment()
transaction.add(this.frame.id, mapFragment) ---> here is the problem
transaction.commit()
```

Someone knows the reason?

Comment: please post all the content of `MapFragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 different classes for showing map in fragment:

1. MapFragment
2. SupportMapFragment

You must use correct one your activity.

1. If Activity is just `Activity` and you use just `FragmentManager` - use `MapFragment`
2. If activity is `AppCompatActivity` and you use `SupportFragmentManager` - use `SupportMapFragment`

Comment: Now I have an other question, I create a CustomSupportFragmentManager (child of SupportFragmentManager) to intercept onTouch Event, with a TouchableWrapper (child of FrameLayout), but never get the onTouchEvent in Huawei, for Google yes. Do you know why?

Comment: Maybe you need to override `dispatchTouchEvent` in TouchableWrapper and manually pass MotionEvent to dispatchTouchEvent of mapView?

Comment: Check my question in here please, I posted some of my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229963/huawei-map-inside-nested-scroll